# How Can I Set price Column Optional for Virtual Products Only

Tags: magento-1.9, price

I need to set price optional for Virtual particular products, not for my all products. How can i import items without price.

**Note : not for my all products.**

Comment: Can't you just set a price at 0 for these products?

Comment: One think, price value dont display.

Answer (score 1):

You can remove the validation of the price field is done entirely by front-end validation.

By removing "required-entry" and "validate-zero-or-greater" from the **class** attribute of the price input, you can disable the validation:

[image: Price input]

Without knowing your criteria for products that should not have price required, I cannot help with applying only to specific procucts.

Comment: @ Tim : Actually i need to import Virtual products, which means details get from user like costumes products(height, length, etc), so don't able display price. I hope you understand my requirement.